# Copy constructor with 2 argument

Tags: c++

```
    class Sample
    {
       public:
       Sample(){}
       Sample(const Sample& obj){ cout<<"C.C. with 1 argument called"<<endl;}
       Sample(const Sample& obj, int i){ cout<<"C.C. with 2 arguments called"<<endl;}
    };
    void main()
    {
         Sample s1;
         Sample s2 = s1; // Here, C.C with 1 arg. called.
    }
```

> There are few questions:
>
> > 1. How I can make a call to copy constructor having 2 arguments?
> > 2. When we require a copy constructor with 1 argument and when we require C.C with 2 argument?

Comment: Sample s2 = s1; // Here, C.C with 1 arg. called. You are calling the assignment operator here.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi: No, that's calling the copy constructor.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You are right! I never realize that this is equivalent to Sample s2(s1); Is it standard or a compiler optimization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A constructor with 2 (or more) *required* arguments is *not* a copy constructor.

1.:

```
Sample s2(s1, 0);
```

Comment: ...unless the first parameter is a possibly cv qualified reference to the class type and all bar possibly the first parameter have default values.

Comment: Actually that can be copy-constructor iff the second parameter has default value.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add little formalism here. Standard has strict definition for "Copy constructor" term (12.8 ):

`A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&,
volatile X& or const volatile X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters
have default arguments (8.3.6). [ Example: X::X(const X&) and X::X(X&,int=1) are copy constructors.`

Answer (score 2):

A class will only really have one copy ctor, which can be invoked with only one argument. It can take two (or more) arguments, but only if it provides default values for the other arguments. Either way, the first argument must be a (normally const) reference to an object of the same type.

Your second ctor taking two arguments isn't really a copy ctor (at least as the term is normally used) -- it's just a ctor that happens to take an instance as an argument (may base the new instance on that argument, at least in part).

Comment: *"A class will only really have one copy ctor"*.. Is it? I think a class can have more than one copy-constructor.

Comment: @Nawaz: yes and no -- yes, in theory you could have several overloads any of which could qualify. But, if you did that, and ever actually tried to *use* one of them in copy ctor fashion, the code wouldn't compile because it would be ambiguous.

Comment: @Nawaz: that would be ambiguous, wouldn't it?

Comment: You mean to say like:  if you are trying to pass 2 or more arguments in C.C, then actually the compiler will treat that constructor as a normal parameterized constructor and it is NO MORE a C.C ?

Comment: @user1168582: Yes, that's pretty much right. If you have to pass any parameter other than the object being copied, then it's no longer a copy ctor.